# Codeigniter Value Not Setting

Tags: php, arrays, forms, codeigniter

I am having an issue with my code and that is that on submit the selected value for `user_support_documentaries` is not being submitted to the array

I can view the HTML source before page submit and it shows the value tag as populated - I cannot get why the selected item is not being put into the array.

**HTML:**

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="user_dafapp_1" name="user_dafapp" value="1" class="checkbox" <?php echo selected_checkbox(set_value('user_dafapp',$grant['user_dafapp']) == 1) ?> /> <br />
</label>
     <div id="user_support_documentaries_container" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo form_dropdown('user_support_documentaries', $film_list, set_value('user_support_documentaries',$grant['user_support_documentaries']), 'id="user_support_documentaries"'); ?>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
// checkout form enhancement
    if ($("#user_dafapp_1").is(":checked")) // If checked
    {
        $("#user_support_documentaries_container").show("fast"); //show the hidden div
    }
    else
    {
        $("#user_support_documentaries_container").hide("fast"); //otherwise, hide it
    }
    $("input[name*='user_dafapp']").click(function ()
    {
        if ($("#user_dafapp_1").is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#user_support_documentaries_container").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#user_support_documentaries_container").hide("fast");
        }

    });
```

**Controller:**

```
function op($action = NULL, $grant_id = NULL)
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('user_role') != 'grantmaker')
        {
            redirect('grants');
        }

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $results = $this->users_model->get_user_by_id($user_id);
        $this->data['user'] = $results->row_array();

        switch ($action) {

            case "edit" :

                $results = $this->grant_model->get($grant_id, $user_id);

                if ($results->num_rows() == 0)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Grant not found', 'error');
                    redirect('user/my_grants');
                }

                $grant = $results->row_array();

                $this->data['submit_text'] = 'Save changes';

                $page_title = 'Edit a grant';
            break;

            case "add" :

                $grant = array(
                                'user_budget'                   => '',
                                'user_dafapp'                   => '',
                                'user_support_documentaries'    => '',
                                'related_filmmakers'            => '',
                                'user_related_filmmakers'       => '',
                                'user_anoymous'                 => '',
                            );

                $this->data['submit_text'] = 'Submit';
                $page_title = 'Make a Grant application form';
            break;
            default :

                $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'grant not found', 'error');
                redirect('user/my_grants');

            break;

        }

        $this->data['action'] = $action;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_budget','Budget','required|numeric|trim|xss_clean'); //Amount
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_dafapp','Support','trim|xss_clean'); //Support
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_support_documentaries','Support documentaries','trim|xss_clean'); //FILMS

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {   
            $this->data['grant'] = $grant;

            $this->data['grant_id'] = $grant_id;

            $this->data['film_list'] = $this->film_model->get_select_options2();

            build_page('user/my_grants/grant/op/add_edit_form', $this->data, $page_title, 'User');
        }
        else
        {
            $grant_data['user_budget']                  = set_value('user_budget'); //Amount
            $grant_data['user_dafapp']                  = set_value('user_dafapp'); //Support
            $grant_data['user_support_documentaries']   = ((set_value('user_dafapp') == 1) ? set_value('user_support_documentaries') : ''); //This Line 


            switch($action) 
            {
                case('edit'):

                    $grant_data['grant_modified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    if ($this->grant_model->save($grant_data, 'edit', $grant_id) == TRUE)
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Grant updated', 'success');
                    }

                break;

                case('add'):

                    $grant_data['grant_created']    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $grant_data['user_id']  = $user_id;
                    $grant_data['grant_active'] = 0;

                    if ($this->grant_model->save($grant_data, 'add', $grant_id) == FALSE) 
                    {
                        log_message('error', "Failed to add grant {$grant_id} via the admin section");
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Failed to add grant - '.set_value('grant_name'), 'error');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $responder_array = array(
                            '%user_budget'                  => set_value('user_budget'),
                            '%user_dafapp'                  => ((set_value('user_dafapp') == 1) ? 'Support one or more documentaries on Name Approved List of films' : 'Support the general operations of Name'),
                            '%user_support_documentaries'   => ((set_value('user_dafapp') == 1) ? set_value('user_support_documentaries') : '')
                            );

                        /*
                                                $responder_array = array(
                            '%user_budget'                  => set_value('user_budget'),
                            '%user_dafapp'                  => ((set_value('user_dafapp') == 2) ? 'Support one or more documentaries on Name Approved List of films' : 'Support the general operations of Name'),
                            '%user_support_documentaries'   => ((set_value('user_dafapp') == 2) ? set_value('user_support_documentaries') : ''),
                            '%user_related_filmmakers'      => ((set_value('related_filmmakers')) ? set_value('user_related_filmmakers') : ''),
                            '%user_anoymous'                => ((set_value('user_anoymous')) ? 'Yes' : 'No'),
                            );
                            */
                        @$this->autoresponder->send('add_grant', $this->session->userdata('user_email'), $this->session->userdata('user_first_name') . " ". $this->session->userdata('user_surname'), $responder_array);
                        @$this->autoresponder->send('add_grant', NOTIFICATION_EMAIL, NULL, $responder_array);

                        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Your grant submission was successful', 'success');
                    }

                break;
            }

            redirect("user/my_grants");         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to pass "user_support_documentaries" without that condition of ((set_value('user_dafapp') == 2)?

Comment: @mariotanenbaum That shows it in the array :)

Comment: are you doing anything to the select with jquery/javascript cause i see `style="display: none;"` there...if yes can u post that code too

Comment: @bipen I have done this :)

Comment: seems there is nothing wrong (from what i have seen in the code you provided).. and this is weird... i think there is something missing somewhere else... :)...

Comment: @bipen correct :) but where

Comment: :).. i don't know.. have to see your full code i guess.. :) :).. are you gettin any error ??

Comment: @bipen  I have just put up the whole function - no error

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
$("#user_dafapp_1").is(":checked")
```

with

```
$("#user_dafapp_1").attr("checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the `id` being set to `radio` and then using the CI `checkbox` code:

**Working Code:**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="user_dafapp_1" name="user_dafapp" value="1" class="checkbox" <?php echo selected_checkbox(set_value('user_dafapp',$grant['user_dafapp']) == 1) ?> /> <br />
</label>
     <div id="user_support_documentaries_container" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo form_dropdown('user_support_documentaries', $film_list, set_value('user_support_documentaries',$grant['user_support_documentaries']), 'id="user_support_documentaries"'); ?>
</div>
```